# hoping to use the Reader interface in order to make my binary files import code cleaner

Tags: go, parsing, decode, binaryfiles

I am well aware that `encoding/binary` doesn't work with variadic types (like string). My problem is as follows:

I have some old binary files produced with a program written in pascal language. I would have been able to read it easily, if it weren't for the string types. Pascal allows you to declare a string with a maximum length (the length cannot exceed 255 characters), but it saves it to a file with less number of bytes to save disk space. So for instance, if I would have the following declaration:

```pascal
var a_string: string[200];
a_string := "AAAA"
```

then the file would end up with the following bytes:

```
0x04 0x41 0x41 0x41 0x41
^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 |           +---------- content
 +---------------------- length
```

so far so good, nothing particularly controversial about that. My problem is that I was trying to hook it up to binary.Read and it obviously fails because binary.Read can only parse fixed size structures. My problem is, however that the only way to read this structure is in the following way:

https://go.dev/play/p/OZRgaDqh9cc

sure it works, but it looks ugly. Imagine that there are, say, 13 fields within the struct and there are only 3 fields that are of pascal string type. Is there something that I am missing ? in other words, is there some use of the Reader interface I wasn't able to google out ? basically the only thing I'm trying to do here is to override the behavior of bytes.Reader for this one custom type.

There are two approaches that I can think of that come to my mind. First would be to iterate trough the struct via reflection and react accordingly of the field happens to be of pascal string type. But that seems like a massive overkill.

Second approach:

1/ wrap the "pure" types which I can read with the regular `binary.Read` in a sub-struct

2/ use `totalBytesRead, _ = reader.Seek(0, os.SEEK_CUR)` to obtain the "current" position within the buffer

3/ read the pascal string using the custom `.Read()` (which would return `bytesRead`) and increment `totalBytesRead` by `bytesRead`

4/ use `reader.Seek(totalBytesRead, os.SEEK_SET)` and continue to use `binary.Read`

but it still seems just .. awkward and my intuition tells me I'm doing this wrong

What I have also tried:

- create a type alias like so, in the hope to tricking encoding/binary into thinking that it simply needs to allocate a bigger buffer:

```golang
type PString [255]byte
```

- look at existing implementations of the binary protocols. So fo instance I took a look at this code: https://github.com/elcapitansam/gostruct/tree/master but that's slightly different problem because it decodes into "pure" interfaces. my problem is slightly different because I already know what is the target interface I want to parse.

Comment: If you want a general solution, write a function that uses reflection to discover struct types and create a list of offsets and type information for each field. For each type, you can have a deserializer, using `encoding/binary` for some, and a string deserializer for others. Then using this structure you can read a stream and parse it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the reflection approach and here's the solution I was able to implement:

https://go.dev/play/p/MPBOmQAmECl

(it uses a dynamic map of codecs instead of hardcoding everything inside the function)

it still seems awfully overcomplicated to me.. what I mean is I always thought that using reflection would be the solution if everything else fails, but my problem seems to be so easy that this solution just somehow seems wrong, at least intuitively. Plus, in this approach one still needs to implement the decoder function for all the int / uint and float types

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

// decoder function receives a source byte slice and a destination pointer
// it returns number of bytes that have been parsed and optionally an error
type Decoder func(src []byte, dest reflect.Value, structField reflect.StructField) (int, error)

type BinaryDecoder struct {
    Codecs map[reflect.Kind]Decoder
}

func (d *BinaryDecoder) Unpack(src []byte, dst interface{}) (int, error) {
    return d.unpackRecursive(src, dst, reflect.StructField{})
}

func (d *BinaryDecoder) unpackRecursive(src []byte, dst interface{}, structField reflect.StructField) (int, error) {
    var bytesRead int = 0
    var err error

    dstValue := reflect.ValueOf(dst)
    dstType := dstValue.Type()

    if dstValue.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        dstValue = dstValue.Elem()
        dstType = dstType.Elem()
    }

    valueType := dstValue.Kind()

    switch valueType {
    case reflect.Struct:
        // let's unpack the struct field by field.
        for i := 0; i < dstValue.NumField(); i += 1 {
            structField := dstValue.Field(i)
            fmt.Printf("%d'th field has a name of %s and is of type %v\n", i, structField.Type().Name(), structField.Kind())
            fmt.Printf("bin tag: %v\n", dstType.Field(i).Tag.Get("bin"))
            if bytesRead, err = d.unpackRecursive(src, structField.Addr().Interface(), dstType.Field(i)); err != nil {
                return -1, fmt.Errorf("unable to unpack struct: %v", err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("Read %d bytes from %s\n", bytesRead, structField.Type().Name())
            src = src[bytesRead:]
        }
    case reflect.Array:
        declaredSize := dstType.Size()
        fmt.Printf("begin to unpack array; declaredSize=%d\n", declaredSize)
        for i := 0; i < int(declaredSize); i += 1 {
            if bytesRead, err = d.unpackRecursive(src, dstValue.Index(i).Addr().Interface(), structField); err != nil {
                return -1, fmt.Errorf("unable to unpack array at position %d: %v", i, err)
            }
            src = src[bytesRead:]
        }

    default:
        decoder, exists := d.Codecs[valueType]
        if !exists {
            return -1, fmt.Errorf("unsupported value type: %v", valueType)
        }

        return decoder(src, dstValue, structField)
    }

    return bytesRead, nil
}

type NestedStruct struct {
    PasString string `bin:"p"`
}

type BinaryStruct struct {
    IntField uint16
    Nested   NestedStruct
    Array    [10]byte
}

func decodeUint8(src []byte, dest reflect.Value, structField reflect.StructField) (int, error) {
    dest.SetUint(uint64(src[0]))
    return 1, nil
}

func decodeUint16(src []byte, dest reflect.Value, structField reflect.StructField) (int, error) {
    var tmpVal uint16
    if err := binary.Read(bytes.NewReader(src), binary.LittleEndian, &tmpVal); err != nil {
        return -1, fmt.Errorf("unable to decode uint16: %v", err)
    }
    dest.SetUint(uint64(tmpVal))
    return 2, nil
}

func decodeString(src []byte, dest reflect.Value, structField reflect.StructField) (int, error) {
    if structField.Tag.Get("bin") != "p" {
        return -1, fmt.Errorf("unsupported string type")
    }
    declaredLength := int(src[0])
    dest.SetString(string(src[1 : declaredLength+1]))

    return declaredLength + 1, nil
}

func main() {
    var srcBytes = []byte{
        0x00, 0x01, // uint16
        0x04, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, // string
        0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, // array of 10 bytes
    }

    var bin BinaryStruct
    var numBytes int
    var err error

    decoder := &BinaryDecoder{
        Codecs: map[reflect.Kind]Decoder{
            reflect.Uint8:  decodeUint8,
            reflect.Uint16: decodeUint16,
            reflect.String: decodeString,
        },
    }

    numBytes, err = decoder.Unpack(srcBytes, &bin)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error unpacking structure: %v\n", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Read %d bytes; end structure: %+v\n", numBytes, bin)
}
```